# Windows10のVirtualBoxでのエラー

Tags: windows, virtualbox

はじめて仮想環境を構築している際のエラーであり、つまり、一度も起動しません。
導入しようとしているOSはCent OS 8です。

[image: エラー画面]

```
仮想マシン"CentOs 8"のセッションを開けませんでした。 Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0)
(VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE). VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU
modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED). 終了コード : E_FAIL (0x80004005)
コンポーネント: ConsoleWrap インターフェース: IConsole
{872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

#### 試したこと

- Hyper-V関連
  もともとHyper-Vは無効にしていました。
- VirtualBox

  再インストール、および、他のバージョンでの確認。
  6.1.28は問題が生じるため、バージョンダウンを解決方法としているページもありました。
  加えて、6.1.30で修正済みとの情報があったため、確認しましたが下記すべてで同じ現象です。

  6.1.26, 6.1.28, 6.1.40
- Disable Device Guard and Credential Guard
  未定義だったため、無効化。
- セキュリティツール
  ESETが動作しているので、ファイヤーウォールとコンピュータ保護の無効化

同様の現象が多いようで情報はたくさん見受けるのですが、解決に至りません。
なにか分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、アドバイス願えますでしょうか。

Comment: エラーメッセージを読む限りだと、Hyper-V関連が有効でないためエラーになっているようですが、現在は無効にされているということでしょうか。

Comment: 過去の情報では、6.1.28はHyper-V共存がとの共存が不可のため、VirtualBoxのバージョンを落とすか、これを停止するとありました。
その後の6.1.30で修正済み、つまり共存可能と認識しました。
VirtualBoxの動作にHyper-Vが必要なのでしょうか？
いずれにしても、Hyper-Vが有効でも同じエラーが生じます。

Comment: CPUは何ですか？もし、Intel製であれば、 https://www.intel.co.jp/content/www/jp/ja/support/articles/000005486/processors.html を参考に、インテルプロセッサー識別ユーティリティーの「インテルバーチャライゼーション・テクノロジー」「拡張ページテーブル(EPT)搭載インテルVT-x」とタスクマネージャーの「仮想化」の状態がどうなっているか(有効か無効か)を追記してください。

Comment: CPUはCore i7-4790です。
インテル® バーチャライゼーション・テクノロジー (VT-x)‡　はい
ダイレクト I/O 向けインテル® バーチャライゼーション・テクノロジー (VT-d) ‡　はい
インテル® VT-x 拡張ページテーブル (EPT)‡　はい

タスクマネージャーに「仮想化」の項目はありませんが、「仮想マシン管理サービス」の Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management が稼働しているようです。

Comment: 確認して欲しいことがズレているようですので、より詳細に書きます。次①から⑤を順に実施してください。
①  https://www.intel.co.jp/content/www/jp/ja/download/12136/28539/intel-processor-identification-utility-windows-version.html からIntel Processor Identification Utility.exeをダウンロードする。
② ダウンロードしたexeを実行してインストールする。 
③ スタートメニューから Intel Processor Identification Utility を起動する。 
④ 起動したインテルプロセッサ識別ユーティリティーで「CPU テクノロジー」と書かれた部分をクリックする。 
⑤ 表示された画面のスクリーンショットを質問に貼り付ける。

Comment: 次にタスクマネージャーです。
① Ctrl + Shift + ESC を押して「タスク マネージャー」を起動する。
② 左下の「詳細 (D)」を押す。
③ 上部タブの左から二番目の「パフォーマンス」を開く。
④ 左側の一覧で「CPU」を選択する。
⑤ 表示されたCPUのパフォーマンスの画面のスクリーンショットを質問に貼り付ける。

Comment: 仮想マシンを作ったあと、それにCentOSをインストールしなければいけませんが、それは正常にできたんでしょうか

Comment: 手順を実行しますので、少しお待ちください。
>仮想マシンを作ったあと、それにCentOSをインストールしなければいけませんが、それは正常にできたんでしょうか
できません。はじめての起動時にCentOSのisoファイルを選択しますが、その後、該当のエラーになります。

Comment: ご指示のタスクマネージャーのパフォーマンス-CPUで仮想化が無効になっていたため、BIOSでVirtualization Technology(VTx)を有効化したところ、無事起動しました。
ありがとうございます。
いろいろと確認したい点があるので、少し様子を見てから質問を閉じます。

Comment: 解決したのであれば、良かったです。この質問を後から見た人が参考にするためにも、どうやって解決したのか自己回答をお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己レスです。
いろいろと勘違いがありました。
まず、検索で多く見かけるVirtualBoxの問題は6.1.28はHyper-Vと共存できない現象でした。
すでに数年前にVirtualBox側で解決しているようです。
これを理解しておらず、Hyper-Vの有効無効を試していました。
試していませんが、Hyper-Vが有効であっても、動作しない状態だったと考えます。
コメントを参考にチェックしたところ、両方の土台になるVT-Xがハードウエア上で有効になっていなかったためです。
BIOSで有効化することで無事解決しました。
回答ではありませんでしたが、コメントいただいた方々ありがとうございました。